Am I allowed to walk around holding a poster for my product?
Like, would that be permitted in airports? Or conventions? Or hotels? Public or private property? I would not put the poster up, but instead hold it for people to see. The purpose is advertisement.

Depends on the details, but most likely not. A hotel or convention hall is a property and customers are not expected to advertise.

The legality of so-called "human billboards" varies by jurisdiction. The legality of it generally wouldn't matter so much on private property, though, the owner will usually have wide latitude to simply kick you out.

An airport isn't a free advertising location. it is for passengers and those collecting them, or having taken them. They charge for advertising on their site. Although in UK people are (were) seen walking popular streets wearing a billboard.

@NuclearHoagie In the US, they do not have "wide latitude" to kick you out of private property that is otherwise open to the public. It's much more complicated, see Pruneyard Shopping Center v. Robins.

I think I know the next question Alexandra will ask: Can I wear a T-shirt advertising my product while in an airport?

And the answer probably depends on whether you're in the airport to make use of its facilities (boarding a plane, or shopping in its shops) or just there to advertise.

There's a lot of overlap (both in answers and close reasons) with your previous question on this topic.

Laws prohibiting this would vary widely by jurisdiction, as well as potentially based on the content of the poster. When you ask whether you would be allowed to do this, however, also requires that you consider the rules and preferences of the owners of the airports, convention centers, and hotels you plan to do this in.
These locations are private property, and typically the owners of that property have the right to choose who can use that property and how they can use it. If you were to set up in the lobby of a hotel advertising for a competitor, for example, it's likely that the front desk would ask you to leave, and if you refuse, they could trespass you from the property. Ultimately, that makes this less of a question of the law, and more a question of the policies and preferences of the specific locations you want to advertise in, and the content of your poster.
As for public property, that will depend a lot on local ordinances. Specific municipalities and even specific locations may have legal restrictions on loitering, advertising, or other types of activities.
